# How to prevent NSFetchedResultsController from updating tableview when the controller disappears?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `UITabbar` with multiple controllers in it. One of the controllers is used to add Events to Core Data, while another controller is used to display events as in a UITableView using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Here's the behaviour that I would like to achieve:
Upon disappearing, the UITableView stops updating, and when the user comes back, the entire table view is reloaded. Otherwise, inserting events from the other controller takes longer, as new rows are created in the `UITableView`, even thought it is not visible.

I'm wondering how I can achieve this behavior, as it doesn't seem to work as I expect it would be:

I have set the delegate of the NSFetchedResultsController to nil in `viewWillDisappear`, and restore it in `viewWillAppear`, along with a call to `[UITableView reloadData]`;

Somehow, I do not see the new data, and suspect this is due to the way NSFetchedResultsController stops fetching if it does not have a delegate.

How can I properly "suspend" updates to `UITableView` when it disappears, but still able to see the entire dataset when the controller reappears?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try sending `performFetch:` to the `NSFetchedResultsController` in `viewWillAppear:` after you have set its delegate back to `self`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not have to "suspend" the table view updates. A `UITableView` will anyway only request data from the `NSFetchedResultsController` for *visible* cells. If the the table view is not visible, no updates will be fired.

Did you test if inserting events from another controller really takes longer? I doubt it. What does Instruments say?

If your delegate methods are fired, you could still check if the table view is visible before doing any updates.

After that, you do exactly as suggested by rob: do a `performFetch:` in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Even if there's no real UI updates, `beginUpdates` at `controllerWillChangeContent` and `endUpdates` at `controllerDidChangeContent` are "freezing" FRC thread for some time.

Comment: I'm suffering these freezes. How can I prevent it? My FRC is performing 5k updates and freezing my app for 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `delegate` of the `NSFetchedResultsController` to nil in `viewWillDisappear`, try setting an object of `NSFetchedResultsController` to nil

Answer (score 0):

What about this crude approach? Not tested it.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL bruteForceReload;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.bruteForceReload = NO;
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    self.bruteForceReload = YES;
}

-(void)setBruteForceReload:(BOOL)bruteForceReload {
    _bruteForceReload = bruteForceReload;
    if (_bruteForceReload) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (!self.bruteForceReload) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    if (!self.bruteForceReload) {
        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if (!self.bruteForceReload) {
        UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (!self.bruteForceReload) {
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    } else {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: if the view isn't on screen it would be better to turn off the heavy-weight change tracking of the fetch controller